# Не могу установить и использовать модели ru_core_news_md, en_core_web_lg в spacy 3.0.6 на apple m1

Tags: python, conda, spacy

Устанавливаю ru_core_news_md через следующую команду, где python `3.8.10` установлен через conda:

```
python -m spacy download ru_core_news_sm
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
81883 illegal hardware instruction  python -m spacy download ru_core_news_sm
```

Прежде чем писать этот вопрос, я обновил spacy с 2.3.5 до 3.0.6. Я думаю, что проблема в том числе в обновлении. На старой версии я также получал ошибку при попытке использования этого пакета в коде, но смог скачать его через cli. Пробовал использовать в следующей инструкции:

```
nlp = spacy.load('ru_core_news_sm')
```

Сейчас, в spacy 3.0.6 получаю следующую ошибку:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'ru_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Аналогично с en_core_web_lg, я уверен та же проблема будет с другой моделью отличной от en_core_web_lg, т. к. она была заранее установлена до обновления.

Comment: `load` будет работать только после `download`, он уже скачанную модель загружает. А почему `download` валится не знаю, в `Google Colab` если обновить `spacy`, то всё срабатывает и `download` и `load` потом.

Answer (score 0):

Там явно написано что для spacy 3.1.0

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

#Попробуйте

!pip install spacy

!pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0.tar.gz

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).